# Calling a postgres stored procedure with psycopg2 - invalid transaction termination

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to call a procedure with psycopg2 (from pg_partman run_maintenance_proc()).

I'm able to do a simple `CALL partman.run_maintenance_proc();` from psql command line.
But when I attempt to do the same with psycopg2 I run into this error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTransactionTermination: invalid transaction termination
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function partman.run_maintenance_proc(integer,boolean,boolean) line 43 at COMMIT
```

Here is my code :

```
dbconn = psycopg2.connect(t_dsn)
cursor = dbconn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CALL partman.run_maintenance_proc()')
results = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
dbconn.close()
```

Do you have an idea what might be wrong ?

Edit : the procedure code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE @extschema@.run_maintenance_proc(p_wait int DEFAULT 0, p_analyze boolean DEFAULT NULL, p_jobmon boolean DEFAULT true)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
 
v_adv_lock              boolean;
v_row                   record;
v_sql                   text;
v_tables_list_sql       text;
 
BEGIN
 
v_adv_lock := pg_try_advisory_lock(hashtext('pg_partman run_maintenance'));
IF v_adv_lock = false THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Partman maintenance already running or another session has not released its advisory lock.';
    RETURN;
END IF;
 
v_tables_list_sql := 'SELECT parent_table
            FROM @extschema@.part_config
            WHERE undo_in_progress = false
            AND automatic_maintenance = ''on''';
 
FOR v_row IN EXECUTE v_tables_list_sql
LOOP
/*
 * Run maintenance with a commit between each partition set
 * TODO - Once PG11 is more mainstream, see about more full conversion of run_maintenance function as well as turning 
 *        create_partition* functions into procedures to commit after every child table is made. May need to wait
 *        for more PROCEDURE features as well (return values, search_path, etc).
 *      - Also see about swapping names so this is the main object to call for maintenance instead of a function.
 */
    v_sql := format('SELECT %I.run_maintenance(%L, p_jobmon := %L',
        '@extschema@', v_row.parent_table, p_jobmon);
 
    IF p_analyze IS NOT NULL THEN
        v_sql := v_sql || format(', p_analyze := %L', p_analyze);
    END IF;
        
    v_sql := v_sql || ')';
 
    RAISE DEBUG 'v_sql run_maintenance_proc: %', v_sql;
 
    EXECUTE v_sql;
    COMMIT;
 
    PERFORM pg_sleep(p_wait);
 
END LOOP;
 
PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(hashtext('pg_partman run_maintenance'));
END
$$;
```

Note: I noticed there is a `cursor.callproc` method but it seems to execute a `SELECT`. The error I have if I use callproc : `HINT: To call a procedure, use CALL.`

Database : postgres 12.5
/ Psycog2 version: 2.9.1

Comment: The docs [Callproc](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=callproc#cursor.callproc) explain that. In fact in the new version of `psycopg`(psycopg3) there is no `callproc`. To get an answer to the error you will need to update the question with the code in `run_maintenance_proc()`. Best guess is you are not handling transactions correctly in the procedure.

Comment: Indeed that's what I thought about callproc. I updated the question with the procedure code

Comment: I not understanding what `@extschema@` is doing. That is not a legitimate identifier and I am not seeing where it is being substituted in? Is this procedure being run in something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using psycopg2 for connecting, you can use

> cursor.autocommit=1
> cursor.execute('CALL partman.run_maintenance_proc()')

Can't use this if you're connected through sqlalchemy though,
For sqlalchemy: set autocommit to True while creating your engine
eg)

> import sqlalchemy

> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://test',isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")

Comment: surprisingly this thing actually worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I received an ERROR OF `InvalidTransactionTermination: invalid transaction termination`.
Then I add :
`conn.set_session(autocommit=True)`
it works for me.
The script as following:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname=secret["dbname"],
        user=secret["username"],
        password=secret["password"],
        host=secret["host"],
        sslmode="require",
    )
conn.set_session(autocommit=True)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("Query here")
conn.close()
```

Here is the link:https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html
Under `Transaction control methods and attributes.` it mentioned
`conn.set_session(readonly=True, autocommit=True)`
will set default_transaction_read_only to on and rely on the server to apply the read only state to whatever transaction, implicit or explicit, is executed in the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Aah I think I see the issue. From here [Transaction control](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control):

> It is possible to set the connection in autocommit mode: this way all the commands executed will be immediately committed and no rollback is possible. A few commands (e.g. CREATE DATABASE, VACUUM, CALL on stored procedures using transaction control…) require to be run outside any transaction: in order to be able to run these commands from Psycopg, the connection must be in autocommit mode: you can use the autocommit property.